# ionic 5 angular 10 Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'appendChild')

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, appendchild, angular10

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'appendChild')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'appendChild')
    at StackController.transition (ionic-angular.js:2714:1)
    at ionic-angular.js:2611:1
    at StackController.<anonymous> (ionic-angular.js:2735:1)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (tslib.es6.js:71:42)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:364:1)
    at Zone.run (zone-evergreen.js:123:1)
    at zone-evergreen.js:857:1
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:399:1)
    at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:167:1)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:798:1)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:750:1)
    at zone-evergreen.js:860:1
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:399:1)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:27425:1)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:398:1)
    at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:167:1)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone-evergreen.js:569:1)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone-evergreen.js:484:1)
    at invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:1621:1)
```

I have had this problem for several days. I have read that it is something about navigation, something about how the routes are declared, but I cannot find a concrete solution. I have tried several alternatives but none of them have been successful.

The error occurs, when I navigate between tabs, only there, and it does not affect the flow of the program… for the moment.

It is worth clarifying that I am not using Jquery.

Does anyone have knowledge of this error?

Did someone pass him?

Remember =>
ionic v5
Angular v10.

I think that with that information is fine, if you need more, let me know. Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so, after much research, what was breaking my program was that inside the `<ion-split-pane>` tag was an `<ion-router-outlet>` tag. The **split-pane** uses the router (ion-router-outlet) for various functions (official documentation - a bit sparse - ionicframework.com/docs/v5/api/split-pane ) and what I had to solve was change that tag **ion-router-outlet** to **ion-nav**, and all my problems were fixed. Obviously, inside that component of used ion-split-pane, not in global component. Very Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that somewhere in your code there is a variable assumed to be a valid HTML element, but it is essentially undefined.

An example of `appendChild`:

```js
const node = document.getElementById("foo");
const textnode = document.createTextNode("Water");
node.appendChild(textnode);
```

```html
<div id="foo"></div>
```

And now let's see an example where it doesn't work:

```js
const node = document.getElementById("foo");
const textnode = document.createTextNode("Water");
node.appendChild(textnode);
```

```html
<div id="bar"></div>
```

See that in both cases, the Javascript attempts to find the element having the `id` of `"foo"` and `append` a text node to it. However, in the first example there is such a node, while in the second example I have changed the `id` from `"foo"` to `"bar"` and therefore the element having the `id` of `"foo"` is not found and you get an error.

It is very possible that similarly to this issue, something was searching for an element that did not exist at the time when it was being searched for and nevertheless, its `appendChild` was being called, but the `undefined` value your error complains about has no property called `appendChild`.

Comment: Yes, I understand your answer and it is very well explained. But what happens is that at no time in the application is that method being used. The closest thing to appendChild that we are using is:
`this.epiBox.nativeElement.classList.add("animate__animated", "animate__pulse");`
that function, where **epiBox** is a **@ViewChild** that has a native HTML element.
The @ViewChild in angular is in charge of finding the html elements that we mark, helped with ElementRef. And in that function it would be the most similar to appendChild, so I don't know if that function is in charge of doing it.

Comment: @GuidoGagliardini somewhere in the code you use `appendChild` is being referred to. I believe you that you do not have that in your source-code, but that means that it happens somewhere deeper, as the stack trace also suggests this. while I'm not an expert in Ionic whatsoever, at GitHub someone had an issue resembling your symptoms and it was caused by the presence of a second `ion-menu` which has broken it. See https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/issues/17213

Comment: @GuidoGagliardini so there are lots of things happening under the hood and it is likely that you violated some Ionic rule which manifests in this manner.

Comment: Yes, it is very likely that the problem comes from below. I already saw that solution but it was not useful to me either. Likewise, the application does not fail, the error is there but the application continues its flow without problems. Obviously I don't want to have that error when building, but I'll have to investigate further. Keep investigating! and thank you very much for your answer! :)

Comment: @GuidoGagliardini happy to help! If this anwer turns out to be solving the problem, then you can accept it as the correct answer. If your solution will be different, then you might consider writing an answer and accepting it. Happy coding!

Comment: unfortunately, it is not  a solution. Thanks

Comment: @GuidoGagliardini understood. Then, if you manage to solve it, then it would be great if you would write an answer here and accept it.

Comment: so, after much research, what was breaking my program was that inside the **<ion-split-pane>** tag was an **<ion-router-outlet>** tag.
The split-pane uses the router (ion-router-outlet) for various functions (official documentation - a bit sparse - https://ionicframework.com/docs/v5/api/split-pane ) and what I had to solve was change that **ion-router-outlet** to **ion-nav**, and all my problems were fixed. Obviously, inside that component of used ion-split-pane, not in global component. Very Thanks!

Comment: @GuidoGagliardini I'm happy the issue has been solved.